# How to split Discord fields into x times depending on total characters?

Tags: python, join, split, discord

I have been trying out a way how to split fields in [Discord](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-limits-limits) where each field has a character limitation of 1024 characters.

My problem is that I have only been able to split into two lists whenever the character is between 900-2000 characters however it does happend that I do get characters (listInfo which I will show in code) is above 2000 character total.

What I am trying to figure out is that how I am able to split the Field embed into x times where 0-900 is one field, 900-1800 is second field, 1800-2700 is third field etc etc. (Each field is n + 900).

```
data = []

listInfo = [
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167764|EU 40 - [2]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167765|EU 40.5 - [4]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167766|EU 41 - [4]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167767|EU 42 - [4]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167768|EU 42.5 - [8]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167769|EU 43 - [9]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167770|EU 44 - [14]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167771|EU 44.5 - [8]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167772|EU 45 - [16]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167773|EU 45.5 - [8]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167774|EU 46 - [16]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167775|EU 47 - [5]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167776|EU 47.5 - [4]>',
  '<https://www.justrandomlink.com/?controller=cart&add=1&as=true&qty=1&id_product=20798&token=e4d64f25476dcee4b08744d382dc405b&ipa=167777|EU 48.5 - [4]>'
]


if 900 <= sum(len(i) for i in listInfo) < 2000:

    data.append(
        {
            'title': 'Info',
            'value': '\n'.join(listInfo[:len(listInfo)//2]) if len(listInfo) else '*Info not found*',
            'short': True
        }
    )

    data.append(
        {
            'title': '-',
            'value': '\n'.join(listInfo[len(listInfo)//2:]) if len(listInfo) else '*Info not found*',
            'short': True
        }
    )

elif 0 < sum(len(i) for i in listInfo) < 900:
    data.append(
        {
            'title': 'Info',
            'value': '\n'.join(listInfo) if len(listInfo) else '*Info not found*',
            'short': False
        }
    )
```

I am trying to figure out a smarter way where I dont add another function that is split on 3 and then for 4 etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this is to keep a running total of the current batch size and use that total to determine whether to add to the current batch or to make a new batch.

```
data, character_count, i = [], 0, 0
for j, item in enumerate(listInfo):
    if len(item) + character_count > 900:
        data.append('\n'.join(listInfo[i:j]))
        character_count, i = len(item), j
    else:
        character_count += len(item)
if character_count:
    data.append('\n'.join(listInfo[i:]))
if not data:
    data.append('*Info not found*')
```

If you're fine with this taking a couple steps, rather than using `enumerate` to keep track of where you are in the list and using `.join` inside the enumeration, it's feasible to just batch any new lines and worry about joining them later.

```
data, character_count = [], 0
for item in listInfo:
    if len(item) + character_count > 900:
        data.append([item])
        character_count = len(item)
    else:
        data[-1].append(item)
        character_count += len(item)
data = ['\n'.join(batch) for batch in data]
if not data:
    data.append('*Info not found*')
```

One problem with this is that it takes a lot of space in memory. Rather than appending to a list you can use something called a *generator* to continue providing each batch. If the person calling the generator actually needs a list for some reason they can make one from the generator, but otherwise they can just process the items in a stream.

```
def batch(listInfo):
    batch, count = [], 0
    for item in listInfo:
        if len(item) + count > 900:
            yield batch
            batch, count = [item], len(item)
        else:
            batch.append(item)
            count += len(item)
    if batch:
        yield batch
data = ['\n'.join(x) for x in batch(listInfo)]
if not data:
    data.append('*Info not found*')
```

At some level, there's still the question of whether you want messages that are *exactly* 900 characters (perhaps splitting the incoming messages) or whether you want to keep messages intact. One problem with keeping messages intact and only splitting between messages is that one of your list items can be greater than 900 characters all by itself. All the code I've written implicitly assumes that to not be the case since the exact way you want messages to wrap, not be sent, or otherwise behave in that case is really application dependant.

Comment: Oh lord, Abit mess is going on in my head but I did go on your first suggestions before I saw this edit. The point of all this is basically just to send notification to Discord and then it basically kills the thread (Havent mentioned it but I didnt thought it will go that deep). About the problem with characters that u mentioned is that I have calucated it so 900 would be working fine either way. However I did not quite understand when you mentioned the "a lot of space in memory" did you meant ur second part of code or first one? The first one seemed to work with enumerate for me but is itgood

Comment: Oh, just that `data` is a list, so all the strings are stored in memory at once. If you only needed to work with one at a time (depends on the use case), you could instead use a generator to work with one, work with the next, and so on without ever having *all* of them in memory at once. It doesn't really matter here. All the code shown here gives the same result and has about the same performance -- pick your favorite.

Comment: I modifed the code abit where I didnt needed to use the `data` - I assume removing it it would be fine to use it without adding any extra memory in that case?

Comment: Yep. Should be.

Comment: Great! I appreciate the help! Was working exactly like I wished. I do wonder if it is possible to do `'\n'.join(listInfo[i:]) if len(listInfo) else '*Info not found*'` ? Instead of having the else statement

Comment: Instead of which `else` statement? I'm not seeing a place to put that that would yield the same results as what you had in your question.

Comment: Woops! Thought instead of `if not data: data.append('*Info not found*')` but as you said, I did not mention the whole code but the code that I had trouble with, either way it is not the problem that is questioned here so I will confirm that your question is valid and give you the answer! :)

Comment: Hello! As it is old thread (2019) I wonder if there is by any chances if there could be any improvements be done here :) That would be cool to see! @HansMusgrave